# Rails includes ordered by first associate of a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Having a tough time figuring out how to build this query in active record. I have the following two models:

```
class Event
  has_many :event_times
end

class EventTime
  belongs_to :event
end
```

EventTime has a start_time Timestamp. I want to select Events, using pagination and order them by EventTime start_time. So events that have EventTimes coming up soonest are first. I'm able to put together a query that gets Events ordered by EventTime, but using pagination results in differing number of records due to the fact that an Event can have multiple EventTimes.

The other solution is doing group_by and then applying the pagination to that result. But this requires loading all the EventTimes into memory which will not scale.

Comment: Should the `Event`s with `event_times` in the past (i.e. `start_time < Time.now`) be considered in the query too?

Comment: There is an end_time on EventTime. So yes, I am including EventTimes that have a start_time in the past as long as the end_time is in the future. But this isn't relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: It kind of is, the way you structured the question. You said "EventTimes coming up soonest are first". This means that the ordering shouldn't be by `start_time`, rather the absolute difference between `start_time` and `Time.now` unless you are not including the event_times with `start_times` in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't fear the join; it's fast as long as you have an index set for `event_id` on your `event_times` table. You can group by event and order by the minimum start time. Pagination can be achieved by passing `offset` and `limit` numbers to the query.

```
Event
  .select('event.*, MIN(event_times.start_time) AS min_start_time')
  .joins(:event_times)
  .group('event.id')
  .order('min_start_time')
  .offset(offset)
  .limit(limit)
```

Comment: Great... The MIN() is what I was missing. Thanks!